# Keep getting encoding errors on 3.10.4 if base encoding is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Watching some youtube tutorial. Person using ver 3.8.2, and i installed 3.10.4.
He type smth like this and it works just fine:

```
r = open('file.txt', 'a')
r.write('something' + '\n')
r.write('что-то')
r.close()
```

If i do the same, i get `UnicodeEncodeError`

```
 Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\small\Desktop\test.py", line 3, in <module> r.write('что-то') File "C:\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>
```

and forced to declare encoding for opening file like this:

```
r = open('file.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
r.write('something' + '\n')
r.write('что-то')
r.close()
```

Mainly interested in 2 questions:

1. Is this happening bc of the difference of OS versions (i got latest win10) or python version or smth else maybe?
2. Is there are a way to fix this permanently? *I thought about declaring encoding type at the start of the program but then it will become inflexible in terms of getting strings from different sources if they are not in the base encoding type. In this case i will be forced to make tons of checks for encoding type and converting it to the unicode-8, for example. This solution not looks like the right one.*

Comment: Post the whole error message with full traceback please.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\small\Desktop\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    r.write('что-то')
  File "C:\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: So you're not actually trying to write `'text'` into that file but `'что-то'`?

Comment: Yes, its two different languages, but both languages is readable in utf-8 and on video its working. -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default encoding for the `open` function is [platform dependent](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-locale-encoding):

> On Unix, it is the encoding of the `LC_CTYPE`locale. It can be set with `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, new_locale)`.
>
> On Windows, it is the ANSI code page (ex: `cp1252`).

So yes, it's because of the OS differences. It is a good habit to always specify `encoding` for writing platform independent code.

You can also make it permanent by enabling the [`Python UTF-8 mode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#python-utf-8-mode).

Comment: Thank you a lot, at least now the problem that bothered me for previous half of the course is done and i understand what is happening.

Comment: Checked both links and now i know how to handle this. Can't say how much i appreciate this amount of help! 
And, i noticed how you changed body of my quest so now i understand how i should ask smth like this in the right way. 
Thanks a lot, kind man, who decided to spent time on such noobie. You are breathtaking!